# How to copy all directory from another host to current host on Linux

Tags: command-line, file-transfer, scp, sftp

My current files and directories are hosted with Godaddy.com and they don't allow `scp` over to another host, and I want to get all the pictures for wordpress under `wp-content/uploads/*` but when I tried `sftp -r`

```
#sftp> get -r uploads /www/wp-content/uploads
Invalid flag -r
```

I want to move from Godaddy to Site5 without `scp` what else I can use?

Godaddy I'm using shared hosting the 4GH, so not many option left for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what godaddy / Site5 allow you to do:

- RSYNC:  `rsync [OPTIONS]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST:DEST`
- SFTP: This time archive your files first and then just SFTP the archive

  - `tar czvf archive.tar.gz /wp/files-to-archive/*`
  - `#sftp > get archive.tar.gz`

Comment: Godaddy doesn't support RSYNC and I can't archrive the very large file

Comment: How about using something like this plugin to backup your WP and have it email the zip to you. Slight over kill but the uploaded photos should be in there.

[link]http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backupwordpress/

Comment: actually I learned that your way really helped! first I was using .zip and that one really bad, so I used .tar.gz and it works like charm! now I have done all the backup

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this from a unix-like system, and if Godaddy supplies `tar`, then you can use that to pipe the files through an ssh connection. Basically, from your system you would run:

```
ssh remotehost 'cd /destination && tar cf - files' | tar xvf -
```

This avoids having to save the tarfile on the remote host.  For more details, see [this question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/39027/easiest-way-for-fast-transfer-of-files-between-linux-servers/39111#39111)

Comment: I don't get it. 

It's done now, but your answer is that suppose to use it just to save it or to transfer it too? because what I was looking for is to `tar` the file then transfer from Godaddy to anotehr host

Comment: My example shows how to copy a directory tree to your local system without creating an intermediate tarfile. That is what you were trying to do in your original question.